# Dockerized Django + Nginx startup & mounting issue

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a environment for my personal project however I'm struggling and can't resolve the issue.

I had it working, made some reorganization in the project structure to structure it like i want (or think is best) and broke it trying to fix it :/ And to be honest i had similar issue in the past, I struggled with it ... I guess I did not learn anything and forgot how i fixed it (wasn't dockerized).

The project is just basic default configuration to have it running as I want, so I have the comfort of the CI/CD Jenkins deployment and can run and play across Docker containers.

I will share the relevant parts as well as the project structure.

Project file structure:

```
RaC/
├── django/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── .env
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── files/
│   │   ├── media/
│   │   └── static/
│   └── rac_backend/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── asgi.py
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       ├── wsgi.py
├── jenkins/
├── nginx/
├── postgres/
├── redis/
├── templates/
├── venv/
├── manage.py
└── docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: ./jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home

  rac_backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: django/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./django/files/static:/code/static
      - ./django/files/media:/code/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - django/rac_backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
      - media_volume:/usr/share/nginx/html/media
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - rac_backend

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

volumes:
  jenkins_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  postgres_data:
  redis_data:
```

django/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY django/ .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Set environment variable to ensure Python outputs are sent straight to terminal without being first buffered
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

CMD ["gunicorn", "rac_backend.asgi:application", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

setting.py

```
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../files/static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../files/media')
...
```

So basically my paths are messed up and Django won't start because i get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rac_backend'` which is the result of the CMD run by Dockerfile as it can't locate the module rac_backend.

Error:

```
rac_backend-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rac_backend'
rac_backend-1  | [2024-03-20 21:01:24 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
rac_backend-1  | [2024-03-20 21:01:24 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) exited with code 3
rac_backend-1  | [2024-03-20 21:01:24 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
rac_backend-1  | [2024-03-20 21:01:24 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Also after I run the `docker-compose up` I see that 2 empty media/ and static/ directories are created inside the RaC/ directory, which it the project root. I want to serve those files from Rac/django/files/*.

Today as a desperate measure I spent half a day breaking chatGPT4 :/ ... Please help

I hope it's clear what I'm tring to achieve.
Running django app with nginx running in docker with jenkins for ci/cd pipeline. And see that sweet sweet Django default instalation page change when I commit a first Hello World homepage on http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

The issue is getting the directory structure in your `Dockerfile` consistent with the volume mounts in your `docker-compose.yml`. Here's a stripped-down version of the project that works. You can add back the other services once you have got this working.

```
├── django
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── rac_backend
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── docker-compose.yml
```

`docker-compose.yml` (Note the way that the `volumes` is specified for consistency with the directory layout set up in the `Dockerfile`.)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rac_backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: django/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./django/:/code
    expose:
      - 8000
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY django/ .

RUN ls

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "rac_backend.asgi:application", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

`requirements.txt` (You are likely to have other versions specified here.)

```
gunicorn==21.2.0
uvicorn==0.29.0
Django==4.2.11
```

[image]